# How to get a group with exactly the group members listed?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

A soccer team has 1 or more players. A player belongs 1 or more soccer teams. I have a list of players: `'Bob', 'James', 'Sam'` I want to know which team has exactly those players in it. So the result would be `Red Team` as `Red Team` is the only team with EXACTLY `'Bob', 'James', 'Sam'` in them. Please keep all the joins I have. I know you could technically do it all in the `members` table, but I only built it like this for simplicity.

```
CREATE TABLE teams(
  name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE players(
  name VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE members(
  team_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  player_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_team_name FOREIGN KEY (team_name) REFERENCES teams(name),
  CONSTRAINT FK_player_name FOREIGN KEY (player_name) REFERENCES players(name)
);

INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ('Blue Team');
INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ('Red Team');
INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ('Green Team');
INSERT INTO teams(name) VALUES ('Purple Team');

INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('Sarah');
INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('James');
INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('Mike');
INSERT INTO players(name) VALUES ('Sam');

INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Blue Team', 'Bob');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Green Team', 'Bob');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Green Team', 'Sam');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Green Team', 'James');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Green Team', 'Sarah');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Red Team', 'Bob');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Red Team', 'Sam');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Red Team', 'James');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Purple Team', 'Mike');
INSERT INTO members(team_name, player_name) VALUES ('Purple Team', 'Sam');
```

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t.name
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN members m
  ON t.name = m.team_name
LEFT JOIN players p
  ON m.player_name = p.name
WHERE
  m.player_name in ('Bob', 'James', 'Sam')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause.  If you want *exactly* those members, then you can filter in the `having` clause.  The following assumes that members cannot be duplicated within a team:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM teams t JOIN
     members m
     ON t.name = m.team_name JOIN
     players p
     ON m.player_name = p.name
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN m.player_name IN ('Bob', 'James', 'Sam') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3 AND
       COUNT(*) = 3;
```

EDIT:

An alternative method uses `LISTAGG()`:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM teams t JOIN
     members m
     ON t.name = m.team_name JOIN
     players p
     ON m.player_name = p.name
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING LISTAGG(m.player_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY m.player_name) = 'Bob,James,Sam';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aa570225f31eb5475849d890fb839596) is a db<>fiddle.

This can be convenient if you only want to pass in one parameter.  However, the names have to be in the correct order for the comparison.

Comment: You have put the number `3` in the SQL statement twice. Is this because there are 3 members in the list? If yes, is there a way I can programmatically do that so it saves me from typing `3`?

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov Please, do not say *doesn't work*, because we cannot see your screen. Post actual error message or explain what do you think is wrong

Comment: @ZoeyMalkov . . . It works.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @astentx Sorry my bad. I said it didn't work because it did not return any results

Comment: @GordonLinoff It works now after the edit. I believe the edit was removing the spaces between the list of names.